# Is there a .NET port of the SED stream editor

Tags: c#, .net, sed, porting

Is there a .NET port of the SED stream editor? Ideally it would be open source, but at this stage I'm not ruling anything out.

I have googled for this already without any obvious hits, so the secondary question here is: How hard would it be to create one?

I assume the sources for SED are in C. If the answer to my primary question is No, I would appreciate pointers/strategies for porting such a project to C#.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply shell out to `sed`?

Comment: Yes - The idea is to integrate a sed processor into a server pipeline where everything else is .NET assemblies.

Comment: @DominicCronin: Did you solve this? And how?

Comment: @frankhommers As it was clear that no existing port was to be found, I didn't follow this direction any further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a mingw build including [sed from msys](http://mingw.org/wiki/msys), [build a dll](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/mingw/dll.html), then [call the dll](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/call_dll.html) from C#.

The [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project includes a sed port and a minised.

**References**

- [Building Windows DLLs with MinGW](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/)
- [How to compile C program as dll in Mingw for use with Inno Setup & callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521921/1113772)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I think it's clear that no-one knows of any existing ports. What you have proposed looks like a viable strategy.