# How to execute 7zip without blocking the Inno Setup UI?

Tags: callback, compression, inno-setup, 7zip, pascalscript

My Inno Setup GUI is frozen during unzip operations.

I've a `procedure DoUnzip(source: String; targetdir: String)` with the core

```pascal
unzipTool := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7za.exe');

Exec(unzipTool, ' x "' + source + '" -o"' + targetdir + '" -y',
     '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode);
```

This procedure is called multiple times and the `Exec` operation blocks the user interface. There is only a very short moment between the executions, where the Inno GUI is dragable/moveable.

I know that there are other options for `TExecWait` instead of `ewWaitUntilTerminated`, like `ewNoWait` and `ewWaitUntilIdle`, but unfortunately they are not helpful in this case. Using `ewNoWait` would result in the execution of multiple unzip operations at the same time.

**I'm looking for a way to execute an external unzip operation and wait for it to finish, but without blocking the user interface. How can i implement that?**

---

Here are my notes and ideas:

Waiting for a process to finish, is blocking, unless you'll be waiting in a thread different from the main one. I think some kind of callback is needed, which is executed, when the unzip operation finishes.

I'm aware that Inno Setup doesn't provide this feature out of the box, see https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/149

While searching for related issues on Stack Overflow, I came up with the question [Using callback to display filenames from external decompression dll in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18650985/1163786), where I found [Mirals's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668202/1163786). It's using InnoCallback combined with another DLL.

I think, in my case this could be `7zxa.dll` for the unzip operation. But it doesn't accept a callback. So, the following code is just a concept / idea draft. One problem is, that `7zxa.dll` doesn't accept a callback.
Another problem is that the 7zxa API is not really inviting to work with.

```pascal
[Code]
type 
    TMyCallback = procedure(Filename: PChar);

{ wrapper to tell callback function to InnoCallback }
function WrapMyCallback(Callback: TMyCallback; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'WrapCallback@files:innocallback.dll stdcall';

{ the call to the unzip dll }
{ P!: the 7zxa.dll doesn't accept a callback }
procedure DoUnzipDll(Blah: Integer; Foo: String; ...; Callback: LongWord);
  external 'DoUnzipDll@files:7zxa.dll stdcall';

{ the actual callback action }
procedure MyCallback(Filename: PChar);
begin
    { refresh the GUI }
end;

{ ----- }

var Callback : LongWord;

{ tell innocallback the callback procedure as 1 parameter }
Callback := WrapMyCallback(@MyCallback, 1); 

{ pass the wrapped callback to the unzip DLL  }
DoUnzipDll(source, target, ..., Callback);

procedure DoUnzip(src, target : String);
begin
  DoUnzipDll(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;
```

---

Update: @Rik suggested to combine the WinAPI function `ShellExecuteEx()` with INFINITE `WaitForSingleObject`.

I've implemented and tested this approach. The code is below.

The unzipping works, but the Inno Setup window is only moveable/dragable for a short moment between the individual unzip operations. During a long running unzip the GUI is fully unresponsive - no dragging/no cancel button.
I've added `BringToFrontAndRestore()`, but it seems the new process has the focus.

```pascal
const
  WAIT_OBJECT_0 = $0;
  WAIT_TIMEOUT = $00000102;
  SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = $00000040;
  INFINITE = $FFFFFFFF;     { Infinite timeout }

type
  TShellExecuteInfo = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    fMask: Cardinal;
    Wnd: HWND;
    lpVerb: string;
    lpFile: string;
    lpParameters: string;
    lpDirectory: string;
    nShow: Integer;
    hInstApp: THandle;    
    lpIDList: DWORD;
    lpClass: string;
    hkeyClass: THandle;
    dwHotKey: DWORD;
    hMonitor: THandle;
    hProcess: THandle;
  end;

function ShellExecuteEx(var lpExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo): BOOL; 
  external 'ShellExecuteEx{#AW}@shell32.dll stdcall';
function WaitForSingleObject(hHandle: THandle; dwMilliseconds: DWORD): DWORD; 
  external 'WaitForSingleObject@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function CloseHandle(hObject: THandle): BOOL; external 'CloseHandle@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure DoUnzip(source: String; targetdir: String);
var
  unzipTool, unzipParams : String;     { path to unzip util }
  ReturnCode  : Integer;  { errorcode }
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    { source might contain {tmp} or {app} constant, so expand/resolve it to path name }
    source := ExpandConstant(source);

    unzipTool := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7za.exe');
    unzipParams := ' x "' + source + '" -o"' + targetdir + '" -y';

    ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
    ExecInfo.lpFile := unzipTool;
    ExecInfo.lpParameters := unzipParams;
    ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

    if not FileExists(unzipTool)
    then MsgBox('UnzipTool not found: ' + unzipTool, mbError, MB_OK)
    else if not FileExists(source)
    then MsgBox('File was not found while trying to unzip: ' + source, mbError, MB_OK)
    else begin 
          
          { ShellExecuteEx combined with INFINITE WaitForSingleObject }
          
          if ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
          begin
            while WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0
            do begin
                InstallPage.Surface.Update;          
                { BringToFrontAndRestore; }
                WizardForm.Refresh();
            end;
            CloseHandle(ExecInfo.hProcess);
          end; 
      
    end;
end;
```

Comment: See also [my answer to Inno Setup: How to modify long running script so it will not freeze GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14385393/850848#45071489)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I suspected using `INFINITE` with `WaitForSingleObject` still blocks the main-thread. Next I thought using a smaller timeout with `WaitForSingleObject`. But the problem is still that the main-thread stays in the while loop of `WaitForSingleObject` and doesn't respond to moving. `WizardForm.Refresh` does not make it movable. It just refreshes the form but doesn't process other messages (like `WM_MOVE`). You need something like `Application.ProcessMessages` to allow the windows to move. Since Inno Setup doesn't have a `ProcessMessages` we could create one ourselves.

Below is your code with a `ProcessMessage` implemented. It does a 100 millisecond wait for `WaitForSingleObject` and if it's still in the wait-state it executes the `ProcessMessage` and `Refresh`. This will allow you to move the window. You can play a little with the value 100.

Another way could be that you save the `ExecInfo` and go on with some other install-part. In the final page you could check if the process is finished. If it's not loop with the `AppProcessMessage` until it is.

```pascal
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

const
  WAIT_OBJECT_0 = $0;
  WAIT_TIMEOUT = $00000102;
  SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = $00000040;
  INFINITE = $FFFFFFFF;     { Infinite timeout }

type
  TShellExecuteInfo = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    fMask: Cardinal;
    Wnd: HWND;
    lpVerb: string;
    lpFile: string;
    lpParameters: string;
    lpDirectory: string;
    nShow: Integer;
    hInstApp: THandle;    
    lpIDList: DWORD;
    lpClass: string;
    hkeyClass: THandle;
    dwHotKey: DWORD;
    hMonitor: THandle;
    hProcess: THandle;
  end;

function ShellExecuteEx(var lpExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo): BOOL; 
  external 'ShellExecuteEx{#AW}@shell32.dll stdcall';
function WaitForSingleObject(hHandle: THandle; dwMilliseconds: DWORD): DWORD; 
  external 'WaitForSingleObject@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function CloseHandle(hObject: THandle): BOOL; external 'CloseHandle@kernel32.dll stdcall';

{ ----------------------- }
{ "Generic" code, some old "Application.ProcessMessages"-ish procedure }
{ ----------------------- }
type
  TMsg = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    message: UINT;
    wParam: Longint;
    lParam: Longint;
    time: DWORD;
    pt: TPoint;
  end;
 
const
  PM_REMOVE      = 1;
 
function PeekMessage(var lpMsg: TMsg; hWnd: HWND; wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax, wRemoveMsg: UINT): BOOL; external 'PeekMessageA@user32.dll stdcall';
function TranslateMessage(const lpMsg: TMsg): BOOL; external 'TranslateMessage@user32.dll stdcall';
function DispatchMessage(const lpMsg: TMsg): Longint; external 'DispatchMessageA@user32.dll stdcall';
 
procedure AppProcessMessage;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(Msg, WizardForm.Handle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
end;
{ ----------------------- }
{ ----------------------- }


procedure DoUnzip(source: String; targetdir: String);
var
  unzipTool, unzipParams : String;     // path to unzip util
  ReturnCode  : Integer;  // errorcode
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    { source might contain {tmp} or {app} constant, so expand/resolve it to path name }
    source := ExpandConstant(source);

    unzipTool := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\7za.exe');
    unzipParams := ' x "' + source + '" -o"' + targetdir + '" -y';

    ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
    ExecInfo.lpFile := unzipTool;
    ExecInfo.lpParameters := unzipParams;
    ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

    if not FileExists(unzipTool)
    then MsgBox('UnzipTool not found: ' + unzipTool, mbError, MB_OK)
    else if not FileExists(source)
    then MsgBox('File was not found while trying to unzip: ' + source, mbError, MB_OK)
    else begin 

          { ShellExecuteEx combined with INFINITE WaitForSingleObject }

          if ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
          begin
            while WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, 100) = WAIT_TIMEOUT { WAIT_OBJECT_0 }
            do begin
                AppProcessMessage;
                { InstallPage.Surface.Update; }
                { BringToFrontAndRestore; }
                WizardForm.Refresh();
            end;
            CloseHandle(ExecInfo.hProcess);
          end; 

    end;
end;
```

(This code is tested and works for me)

Comment: :) Your changes are spot on: AppProcessMessage with a low timeout does the trick! Thank you very much for your ideas and your time!