# MySQL server discovery on LAN by listening port (Inno Setup)

Tags: mysql, tcp, inno-setup, tcplistener, pascalscript

I need to search for an `IP address`  with `Listening Port` to look up for others PC on LAN (try to discovery MySQL server) and get the results `IP` who has that port listening.

Something similar to this code to test sockets but working in Inno Setup:

```pascal
program pfinger;

uses sockets,errors;

Var
  Addr : TInetSockAddr;
  S : Longint;
  Sin,Sout : Text;
  Line : string;

begin
  Addr.sin_family:=AF_INET;
  { port 79 in network order }
  Addr.sin_port:=79 shl 8;
  { localhost : 127.0.0.1 in network order }
  Addr.sin_addr.s_addr:=((1 shl 24) or 127);
  S:=fpSocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  If Not Connect (S,ADDR,SIN,SOUT) Then
    begin
    Writeln ('Couldn''t connect to localhost');
    Writeln ('Socket error : ',strerror(SocketError));
    halt(1);
    end;
  rewrite (sout);
  reset(sin);
  writeln (sout,paramstr(1));
  flush(sout);
  while not eof(sin) do
    begin
    readln (Sin,line);
    writeln (line);
    end;
  fpShutdown(s,2);
  close (sin);
  close (sout);
end.
```

I've already tried other ways (Java code). But installer is starting slow, when I need to decompress JRE to run Java jar. I try to wrap my Java code, but don't know where/how find Pascal functions similar to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a server is listening on a port, you can use [`Winsock` OLE control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa228119(v=vs.60)):

```pascal
type
  TSocketState =
    (sckClosed, sckOpen, sckListening, sckConnectionPending, sckResolvingHost,
     sckHostResolved, sckConnecting, sckConnected, sckClosing, sckError);

type
  TMsg = record
    hwnd: HWND;
    message: UINT;
    wParam: Longint;
    lParam: Longint;
    time: DWORD;
    pt: TPoint;
  end;

const
  PM_REMOVE = 1;

function PeekMessage(var lpMsg: TMsg; hWnd: HWND; wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax,
  wRemoveMsg: UINT): BOOL; external 'PeekMessageA@user32.dll stdcall';
function TranslateMessage(const lpMsg: TMsg): BOOL;
  external 'TranslateMessage@user32.dll stdcall';
function DispatchMessage(const lpMsg: TMsg): Longint;
  external 'DispatchMessageA@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure AppProcessMessage;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
end;

function CheckPort(Host: string; Port: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Socket: Variant;
begin
  Socket := CreateOleObject('MSWinsock.Winsock');
  Socket.RemoteHost := Host;
  Socket.RemotePort := Port;
  Socket.Connect;

  { Winsock requires message pumping }
  while not (Socket.State in [sckConnected, sckError]) do 
  begin
    AppProcessMessage;
  end;

  Result := (Socket.State = sckConnected);

  if Result then
  begin
    Log(Format('Port %d on %s is open', [Port, Host]));
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Port %d on %s is NOT open', [Port, Host]));
  end;
  Socket.Close;
end;
```

Note that the `Winsock` control requires message queue pumping. So you may need to disable wizard before running the check, to prevent user from messing with the form.

---

*Credits: The `AppProcessMessage` comes from [How to execute 7zip without blocking the InnoSetup UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32256432/850848#32266687)*

Answer (score 2):

My go-to for checking open ports is the **Nmap** program.

An example command to probe address 192.168.200.133 on TCP port 3306 would be this:

```
nmap -sT -sV -Pn -n -p 3306 192.168.200.133
```

You can also scan an entire subnet by giving a CIDR range instead of an IP.  As example, to scan for MySQL instances (TCP port 3306) on 192.168.200.1 - 192.168.200.254, you could do:

```
nmap -sT -sV -Pn -n -p 3306 192.168.200.0/24
```

^^ These examples were taken straight from https://securityblog.gr/1549/discover-open-mysql-ports/

Nmap is very commonly used on Unix/Linux, but has been ported to Windows, first in year 2000, currently supported on Win 7 or newer (including Server 2008).  See https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html