# Keep Inno Setup UI responsive during PrepareToInstall

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, message-pump

In order to keep the Inno Setup UI responsive, I'm using a technique almost identical to the one described in [How to execute 7zip without blocking the InnoSetup UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32256432)  In one of my `[Files]` entries, I defined an `AfterInstall` procedure which runs a lengthy task.  During that time, thanks to the message pump described by the above link, I can still click on the wizard form and move it around, etc.  However, if I attempt to call that same procedure from within the `PrepareToInstall` event handler, I can't click or move the wizard form - it is still completely disabled/frozen.

Is there something special done during `PrepareToInstall` by Inno Setup that would purposely disable the wizard form?

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup [indeed disables window, while running `PrepareToInstall`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_9/Projects/Wizard.pas#L1635).

I do not think you can do anything to prevent that.

---

Consider using [`CreateOutputProgressPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputprogresspage) instead.

See [my answer to Inno Setup: How to modify long running script so it will not freeze GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14385393/850848#45071489) and links from it to other questions showing use of `CreateOutputProgressPage`, for example [Inno Setup Get progress from .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) installer to update progress bar position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39247947/850848).